# Where can I rent a float plane?

Tags: usa, seaplane

Is it possible to rent a float plane with a private pilot's license?

Flying floats is one of the main attractions for me to learn to fly.  However, after some searching on the internet I can only find wheeled aircraft that are available for rent in my area.  Am I missing something?  Are there flying clubs or partnerships that have float planes available?  I would love to fly floats but owning a seaplane is not in the cards for me at this point in my life.

Comment: Do you have a float rating? (Upon rereading your question, it sounds like you might be looking for float *training*. Is that right?)

Comment: I do not have a float rating or a private pilots license yet, all I've done is an introductory flight which I really enjoyed!  I want to pursue flying but curious if I can expect the ability to rent float planes once I have all of the proper training.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Seaplane Pilot's Association](http://www.seaplanes.org/spa/) publishes a [Water Landing Directory](http://www.seaplanes.org/mambo/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=41) that includes seaplane facilities and flight planning maps for cross countries. This lists facilities that offer seaplane rental's. There is a discounted price on the directory for SPA members.